# Should we really change statement into a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Skeptics Stack Exchange is filled with questions of the form

> Is X true?

For example, "Does Global Warming happen?"

Basically we have a statement. The questioner wants to ask whether the statement is true or not.

I think it makes more sense to simply state:

> X?

or

> X

Rather than asking

> Does an apple a day makes you healthy?

We could say

> An apple a day makes you healthy?

or

> An apple a day makes you healthy

since our users know that the Skeptics Stack Exchange is there to test statements.

Comment: Your example changes a question to a statement (with a question mark at the end). Thats the opposite of the title of this meta post. Colour me confused.

Answer (score 3):

While this is quite the norm in other Stack Exchange sites, I don't think it would work here, because using a question as the title, e.g.

> Does an apple a day keep the doctor away?

implies that *we don't know* what the answer is, whereas using a statement, e.g.

> An apple a day keeps the doctor away

implies that we *agree* with the statement.

Since in the majority of cases it turns out that we actually *disagree* with the claims, I don't think that titling the question and thus, the page, and the corresponding search engine result, is correct.